# My collision detector is having my Sprite clip through some walls and collide into others and i don't know why

Tags: java, libgdx, collision

I'm making a Zelda/Pokemon-esque game in LIGBDX and i'm trying to figure out collision detect. I'm using Tiled Maps and have a Wall Layer which i use for collision. Whenever the player tries to move, i use a for loop that checks if it they will collide with a wall. For some reason, the player may stop at some walls perfectly fine but may clip through others.

**Player Movement**

```
public void MoveLeft() {


        for (float i = 0; i < movespeed; i++) {

            if (!M.iswallat(getPosition().getX() - 1, getPosition().getY()) ) {
                getPosition().moveLeft(1, M);
                UpdatePos();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

There are actually 4 methods for each movement type (left, right, up and down). They are all functionally the same with the only difference being what variable is being modified. getPosition is where the position data is stored. UpdatePos moves the Sprite and updates the camera. MoveLeft itself is called by a Timer whenever the boolean IsMovingLeft is active. This boolean is switched on and off by the KeyDown and KeyUp methods in an InputProcessor.

**Is Wall At**

```
public boolean iswallat(float x, float y) {

        int xr =  (int) (x / collisionLayer.getTileWidth());
        int yr =  (int) ( y / collisionLayer.getTileHeight());
        if (collisionLayer.getCell(xr, yr) != null) {

            System.out.println("Cell found at : "+ xr + "," + yr);


            if (collisionLayer.getCell(xr, yr).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("blocked")) {


                return true;
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Found but not blocked!");
                return false;
            }

        }

        else {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

I expect the player to actually collide with and stop at walls and not clip through.

Comment: When the clip-through happens, is the "Cell found at :.." logged? or does it not find a  cell? Does the player sometimes hit "invisible" walls? Are the clip-throughs rather rare or almost always?

Comment: @Cashbee i dont hit invisible walls and the clip through is semi-frequent. Sometimes the player stops at the wall, other times they go through half-way. It doesn't ever pass through completely though.